# Play sound at the position x by means of "read/write"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Belwo is a exmple (from adobe) which works fine. But how can I play the sound at a certain position? E.g. after 10-Second.
Something like

```
mySound.play(10000);
```

It is to use "readFloat/writeFloat" commands (as it is), because I intend to change the speed of sound.

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound(); 
var sourceSnd:Sound = new Sound(); 
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.mp3"); 
sourceSnd.load(urlReq); 
sourceSnd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded); 
function loaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    mySound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processSound); 
    mySound.play(); 
} 
function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void 
{ 
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
        sourceSnd.extract(bytes, 8192); 
        event.data.writeBytes(upOctave(bytes)); 
} 
function upOctave(bytes:ByteArray):ByteArray 
{ 
    var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    bytes.position = 0; 
    while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0) 
    { 
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat()); 
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat()); 
        if (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0) 
        { 
            bytes.position += 8; 
        } 
    } 
    return returnBytes; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does `SoundChannel.position` help?

Comment: You need to **[convert to PCM](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadCompressedDataFromByteArray())** your MP3's bytes into a new byteArray. When it's PCM then its same thing as sampleData so you can do some function that "adjusts" the floats. To playback PCM bytes use **loadPCMFromByteArray** method.

Comment: What's the problem in using `mySound.play(10000);` ? It should work if your sound is longer than 10000 ms.

Comment: @Vesper I think AS3 expects a non-parameter `mySound.play();` to trigger listening for sampleData. He needs to convert the whole MP3 to PCM.

Comment: @VC.One Hmm. Embedding MP3s works directly, loading them from elsewhere should also do. But seeing him trying to resample the audio on the fly AND playing with offset - probably one should first convert the sound into a resampled one, and then play from offset.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found a workaround. Since playing the sound at time-position, needs to find the corresponding byte samples,  instead of time-bar like a audio-player, I offer to user a byte-position-bar. the user can choose the byte position but not the time position.